# Unknown class: java.lang.String in AndroidX two-way data binding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-xml, android-databinding, androidx

Just migrated to AndroidX and this error has appeared when trying to build:

`Unknown class: java.lang.String
file://----/app/src/main/res/layout/my_fragment.xml Line:XXX`

The line in question is the start of an EditText which uses two-way databinding:

`android:text="@={viewModel.myString}"`

`myString` looks like this:

`val myString = MutableLiveData<String>()`

I have multiple instances of this; each one involves two-way data binding in an EditText with a `LiveData<String>`.

Comment: If you just migrated, please double-check that dataBinding version is up-to-date.

Comment: @shkschneider Doesn't it use the same version as the Android Gradle Plugin?

Comment: It usually suffice to put "dataBinding { enabled = true }` it's just that I had problems in the past with this, and had to clean, sync gradle, restart ide, rebuild to fix -- you know, the weird case.

Comment: I'm facing similar issue with a custom BindingAdapter. I'm using AndroidX 1.0.0-rc02. I solved this by using Java for the BindingAdapter. It's not the best solution. I filled up a bug report: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/114838820

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you solved this / how?

Comment: I have this issue too in a rather large, corporate project: using 2-way databinding. In my case I have an ObservableField instead of a MutableLiveData, but the error is the same.I've tried to make a simple standalone app to reproduce this to file a bug report, but so far the standalone app is fine. I'm trying to hunt down the difference between the two apps...

Comment: The inclusion of the following library introduces the bug into my example project (even if I don't use the library at all from code): `implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:2.17.0'`

Comment: I've filed a bug report: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117544947

Comment: I face same issue, is there any possible way without using BindingAdapter?

Answer (score 1):

For those having this issue with databinding v3.4.0, a temporary rollback to 3.3.2 fixed it for me. I posted [an issue about this on their tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132135607) in the meantime.

To rollback, all you have to do is change your `build.gradle` accordingly:

```
android {
    ...
        dataBinding {
            enabled = true
            version = '3.3.2'
        }
    ...
}
```